Old digital backs on medium-format film cameras
What are the benefits of using old digital back (by old I mean devices that has 6x4.5 sensor size and 20-50 mpix resolution) on a medium format camera like Mamiya RZ67, instead of using modern full-frame camera like Canon EOS R5?
Digital back might be a little bit cheaper than a new FF body, but we have to remember you have to have lens, body, viewfinder etc on one side and again lens on the other side.
Am I missing something?

There are no digital backs as large as 6x4.5 (56x42 mm), no matter what Pentax called their "645" digital sensor. It, along with the Hasselblad X1D-50c, H6D-50c, CFV-50c, and Fuji GFX 50S, GFX 100S, etc. are only 43.8x32.9 mm. The Phase One P65+ (53.9x40.4 mm) came closest, followed by the Hasselblad H5D-60c & H6D-100c (53.7x40.2 mm). The crop factor of the Pentax 645D sensor (and the others the same size) to FF is less than that of FF to APS-C. (Pentax "645D" is 1.26X larger linearly than FF, which is 1.6X larger linearly than APS-C.)

There are digital "scan backs" with larger coverage, but they only have a single line of pixel wells and operate much like a flatbed scanner, taking a long time to go from one side of the frame to the other as at uses the same line of pixel wells to scan each column of the photo. Perfectly good for static subjects such as document and art reproduction. Not so good for any scene with movement in it.

If you start from scratch and need to obtain the equipment, there is probably no advantage, but rather a lot of disadvantages. Used, but high quality MF film cameras are not necessarily cheap, so if you get a used MF camera and digital back, you are not likely to pay very much less than for new 35mm format equipemnt.
If you on the other hand already have a good, suitable MF camera and perhaps a selection of lenses, it is likely much cheaper to buy an adapter and an older digital back than to buy new 35mm format equipment with similar image quality. I have a Mamiya RZ67 with a lot of very good glass and I could get an adapter and a very descent older digital back (e.g. Aptus or Phase One) in the 30-40 MP range for that camera for much less than what only a Canon EOS R5 body would cost. If I for example still want to use the MF camera for film, don't bother having much heavier equipment to tug around and don't need the probably much better low-light performance of a new 35mm format camera compared to the older MF digital backs, it would surely be something to consider.
